# Stream.Read return System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to download a large zip (560MB) with the following code:

```cs
DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://report-demo.eyeq.tech/download/Downloads.zip");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream("Downloads.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            DateTime nowTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if ((nowTime - startTime).TotalMinutes > 5)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Download timed out");
            }
            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
    }
}
```

But after a few second of downloading, the program returned `System.IO.IOException: 'The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.'` And the inner Exception is: `Win32Exception: The specified data could not be decrypted`
**EDIT:** The full exception is:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified data could not be decrypted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at WpfApp1.MainWindow.<Download>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\vinh.ngo\Project\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 53
```

Comment: Rather use `HttpClient` than the legacy `WebRequest`.

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with HTTP or downloading files. There's no decryption call in the code. Where did it occur? Post the *full exception text* returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This contains the actual location that threw and the stack trace that shows which calls led to it. You can also get it by clicking on the `Copy Details` link in the exception popup

Comment: BTW you could replace *all* this code with a call to [Stream.CopyToAsync(stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1). To implement timeouts use a CancellationTokenSource with a timeout of 5 minutes and pass the CancellationToken to `CopyToAsync

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the kind reply, here is the full exception: https://justpaste.it/6ne72 . Here is the full program in case you want to have a look: https://filebin.net/j883xtfvfvopaxy9

Comment: Post the text in the question itself

Comment: Are you using Fiddler or some other kind of debugging proxy? Did the connection change or get interrupted perhaps? Switched from WiFi to LAN or something similar? The only way you'd get such an error is if the *SSL connection* threw it. That's the only thing that encrypts/decrypts data in this code. I can't reproduce the error with HttpClient anyway

Comment: Perhaps the *server* stopped the download resulting in incomplete packages sent to the client?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I changed to LAN and it worked! Thank you so much. I'm curious what happened to my network. Anyway, can you leave an answer so I can close this question.

Comment: You forgot to say you have a flaky Wif-Fi connection. Which all of them are, one way or another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem with this

```
var client=new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var url="https://report-demo.eyeq.tech/download/Downloads.zip";
using var stream=await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
using var fi=File.Create(@"c:\somepath.zip");
//Set up a 10" timeout
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
//Copy the data directly
await stream.CopyToAsync(fi,cts.Token);
```

or this

```
var req=System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
using var response = req.GetResponse();
using var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
using var fi=File.Create(@"c:\somepath.zip");
//Set up the timeout
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
//Store the data
await stream.CopyToAsync(fi,cts.Token);
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
```

In .NET Core 3.1 WebRequest uses HttpClient so there's not a huge difference between those snippets.

The only thing that encrypts/decrypts data in this code is the SSL connection. To get a decryption error means the connection was somehow affected. Perhaps the *server* dropped the connection resulting in incomplete packages that failed decryption? Or the connection was interrupted and some data was lost? Is Fiddler or some other debugging proxy used perhaps?

**Update**

`I changed to LAN and it worked` all Wi-Fi connections fail one way or another. Perhaps the signal is weak, or noisy neighbors emit on the same channel, or the telco's cheap router decided to drop some packages out of spite. An overworked router in a cafe may not have the CPU power to handle all connections so it will start dropping low priority packages after a while